# IDE failed to recognize file and report ``Unresolved type``

Tags: goland

I'm using GOLAND and import a package by go mod vendor.

1. It works good with compiling and building.
2. I can find types under this package other than the problematic file
3. I can't find any types defined in the problematic file

I've tried invalidate caches and restart the IDE, however it still not works.

Comment: Could you share a minimal reproducible example to reproduce it? What version of GoLand are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I've find out why. Golang is failed to recognize file larger than 4.19M. Can change the file size limit accroding to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/GO-5029